# Can I see in Trello who visited or viewed board in my organisation

Tags: trello, trello-cards, trello-organization

I added a person to my Organisation Trello board.
He has left but I forgot to remove him from Trello.

Is it possible to see if he has viewed our Boards / Cards after he has left?

I mean I have not still removed him. Is there any way I can get some alert if he views it so I can  catch him? Any logs,  etc.

Comment: AFAIK, Trello doesn't keep accessible logs of views.

Answer (score 2):

For the free account, the only track you can keep is when he/she **changes** anything on the board. Regarding read only access, there is no log you can check for that.

If this is a critical thing you need to solve right now, consider asking Trello support and [reading help](http://help.trello.com/article/831-trello-business-class-vs-trello-gold) if this is available to achive by upgrading to one of the paid plans. Still, I believe this is not possible by this time.